# Show/hide list selecting all instead of individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I have the following code, which shows and hides elements according to buttons being clicked:

HTML:

```
<div class="largeImage">
    <div class="uploadItem.NameContainer">
        <img src="thumbNail1.jpg" alt="thumbNail1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonContainer">
        <div class="editButton">
            <input type="button" value="Click to Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="cancelRenameButton">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="renameButton" >
                <input type="submit" value="Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="selectButton"><input type="button" id="select" value="Select" class="selectImagePath" /></div>
        <div class="deleteButton">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="largeImage">
    <div class="uploadItem.NameContainer">
        <img src="thumbNail2.jpg" alt="thumbNail2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonContainer">
        <div class="editButton">
            <input type="button" value="Click to Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="cancelRenameButton">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="renameButton" >
                <input type="submit" value="Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="selectButton"><input type="button" id="select" value="Select" class="selectImagePath" /></div>
        <div class="deleteButton">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.galleryButtonContainer .cancelRenameButton {display:none;}
.galleryButtonContainer .renameButton {display:none;}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".editButton").click(function () {
    $(".renameButton,.cancelRenameButton").show();
    $(".editButton").hide();
});
$(".cancelRenameButton").click(function () {
    $(".renameButton,.cancelRenameButton").hide();
    $(".editButton").show();
});
```

The problem I'm getting is I can't get the buttons to work individually. I've tried using 'this' without success

Comment: What do you mean with "***can't get the buttons to work individually***" ? That you hide all buttons in page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(".editButton").click(function () {
    $(this).parents(".largeImage").find(".renameButton,.cancelRenameButton").show();
    $(this).parents(".largeImage").find(".editButton").hide();
});
$(".cancelRenameButton").click(function () {
    $(this).parents(".largeImage").find(".renameButton,.cancelRenameButton").hide();
    $(this).parents(".largeImage").find(".editButton").show();
});
```

Comment: There's a typo after the fourth find, errant dot. However, this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `siblings` (less function calls!) in combination with `this` to traverse the DOM and then just `toggle` them away (or keep `hide` and `show` if you prefer).

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5mcspz1/1/)

```
$(".editButton").click(function () {
    $(this).toggle().siblings(".renameButton,.cancelRenameButton").toggle();

});
$(".cancelRenameButton").click(function () {
    $(this).toggle().siblings(".renameButton,.cancelRenameButton").toggle();
});
```

Comment: I never knew about siblings, so I +1'd. Every day's a school day!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly what u want to do. This can be a possible solution:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="largeImage">
    <div class="uploadItem.NameContainer">
        <img src="thumbNail1.jpg" alt="thumbNail1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonContainer">

        <div class="editButton" name="form1">
            <input type="button" value="Click to Rename"/>
        </div>
        <div class="cancelRenameButton" name="form1">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="renameButton" name="form1">
                <input type="submit" value="Rename"/>
        </div>
        <div class="selectButton"><input type="button" id="select" value="Select" class="selectImagePath" /></div>
        <div class="deleteButton">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="largeImage">
    <div class="uploadItem.NameContainer">
        <img src="thumbNail2.jpg" alt="thumbNail2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="galleryButtonContainer">

        <div class="editButton" name="form2">
            <input type="button" value="Click to Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="cancelRenameButton" name="form2">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="renameButton" name="form2">
                <input type="submit" value="Rename" />
        </div>
        <div class="selectButton"><input type="button" id="select" value="Select" class="selectImagePath" /></div>
        <div class="deleteButton">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.galleryButtonContainer .cancelRenameButton {display:none;}
.galleryButtonContainer .renameButton {display:none;}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(".editButton, .cancelRenameButton").click(function () {
    Toggle($(this));
});

function Toggle(obj){
    var name = obj.attr("name");
    $(".renameButton[name="+name+"],.cancelRenameButton[name="+name+"]").toggle();
    $(".editButton[name="+name+"]").toggle();    
}
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqfk4dee/) to see a how it works.
A better solution would be, I think, remove the divs and deal only with buttons.

Hope it useful!